# How to create a global variable in RPM spec file

Tags: linux, rpm

At RPM installation time, I want to determine if the host is UAT or PROD. Once I know, I can then set a variable (say %user, %group) that can be used anywhere in the RPM (our App uses a different Unix user:group for PROD and UAT). Right now, if I need to know if the host is PROD or UAT in both %pre and %post sections, I have to check this in each section due to variable scope - i.e. if %user is being defined in %pre, I cannot use it in %post.

The way I determine if the host is PROD or UAT is a simple regex on the hostname.

I've looked into %global macros but I'm struggling, hence a question to a wider audience.

Thank you in advance

Comment: You don't do this. You create a RPM for UAT and your create a RPM for PROD.

Comment: One of the easiest ways to mark a server as being in the PROD or UAT environment is to make that environment name part of the server's hostname.  E.g., `fooserver.prod.mycompany.net` / `fooserver.uat.mycompany.net`.  Virtual servers in VMware and public services like AWS/Azure/Google have "tags" or "labels" that are associated with the server and these can be queried by scripts to learn the environment name.  Your server launch/provisioning software can create a directory in a place like `/etc/mycompany` and put simple text files there with useful server info for scripts to read.

Comment: Yes, we differentiate PROD and UAT servers in the hostname.   It goes something like:    servername[pu].mycompany.com where the p = prod and u - uat.  I'm currently getting the `hostname` and running a regex to check for 'p' or 'u' at a certain position and that works fine.  My gripe is that I have to do this check in both the %pre and %post sections of the SPEC file because any VARs being set are local to that scriplet.  This is why I want a Global VAR that I can set once and is available to all scriplets in the spec

Comment: @paladin - yes this would work of course.  The reason we use a single RPM across all environments is because we can be sure that the RPM is well tested before it hits Production.  If we use a different RPM for Production, there's no way of testing it until deployment which in my business adds unnecessary risk.   It's horses for courses - I don't think there's a right or wrong way.  Your suggestion also works

Answer (score 2):

The macros in the SPEC file are set during rpmbuild time. I.e. when you are creating the rpm package. During the build time they are expanded and cannot be altered later - e.g., during installation.

If you set macro in the SPEC file based on some content on the disk, then it will be set based on the content of the file on host where you created the RPM package.

If you want to alter your behaviour during installation time then you have to do it in each section again. E.g.

```
%pre
if [ `hostname` -eq 'foo' ]; then
   .....

%post
if [ `hostname` -eq 'foo' ]; then
   .....
```

These sections are interpreted as two separate shell scripts, and there is no way to keep variables between these two runs. I.e. when you set the shell variable in the first scriptlet, it will not propagate to the second one. The recommended way is to drop a file that you re-read in the second scriptlet. https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/packaging-guidelines/Scriptlets/#_saving_state_between_scriptlets

Answer (score 0):

Don't think that single global scope for post and pre macros should exist – in the end, these are really independent scripts that run separately.